# Google Calendar API V3 Delete API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I have a trouble when trying to use delete api ([The documentation from Google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/delete)).
My system is using Google Account Service to create multiple events.
The problem occurs when I try to delete all events by using the delete api
The code in cakephp framework.

```
$service->calendars->delete(GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID);
```

I checked some events on calendar, It could delete some events then return an error

> "code": 500,
>      "message": "Backend Error"

Anybody can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: There is a [Try-it section](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear#try-it). Place your calendarID and Execute.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am using Google Account Service. Your method just for the logged-in user. It is not i desired.

Answer (score 1):

**CakePHP 3.x in  Google Calendar API**

- Follow this steps:
- Create google calendar api project

  https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=calendar&pli=1
  Composer to install:
    "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
      Required google calendar api integration
  https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=calendar&pli=1
  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php
  Create project and create secret key and client id
  Project in set name and redirect URL
  NOTE:- redirect URL must be .com and .org domain
  If you develop in local machine then create follow type of virtual host
              example.com and example.org
  Virtual host create then
  Follow this step:

Set configuration file in app_globle.php

```
[
'Google' => [
      'ClientID' => '7441260037.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'ClientSecret' => 'kashdjahdkjshdkjhjAs',
        'RedirectUrl' => 'http://' . env("HTTP_HOST") . '/oauth2calendars',
        'ClientCredentials' => WWW_ROOT . 'files'. DS.'google.txt',
        'Scopes' => implode(' ', [Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_APPDATA, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA]),
    ]
]
```

**Route**

```
 $routes->connect('/events/add', ['controller' => 'Events', 'action' => 'add', ['_name' => 'add-event']);

    $routes->connect('/events/edit/:id', ['controller' => 'Events', 'action' => 'edit', ['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id'], '_name' => 'edit-event']);

    $routes->connect('/events/delete/:id', ['controller' => 'Events', 'action' => 'delete', ['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id'], '_name' => 'delete-event']);
```

**

- Controller

**

```
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Calendar;
use Google_Service_Calendar_Event;
use Google_Service_Drive;
use Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile;
```

**Authorize the google Oauth**
/**
     * get Google calendar client
     */

```
 private function getClient()
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAccessType("offline");
        $client->setClientId(Configure::read('Google.ClientID'));
        $client->setClientSecret(Configure::read('Google.ClientSecret'));
        $client->setRedirectUri(Configure::read('Google.RedirectUrl'));
        $client->setScopes(Configure::read('Google.Scopes'));
        $credentialsPath = Configure::read('Google.Credentials');
        if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            return $this->redirect($authUrl);
        }
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        // Refresh the token if it's expired.
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
        }
        return $client;
    }
```

/**
     * **Create Google Calendar event**
     */

```
 public function createCredentials()
    {
       $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAccessType("offline");
        $client->setClientId(Configure::read('Google.ClientID'));
        $client->setClientSecret(Configure::read('Google.ClientSecret'));
        $client->setRedirectUri(Configure::read('Google.RedirectUrl'));
        $client->setScopes(Configure::read('Google.Scopes'));

               if (isset($this->request->query['code'])) {
            $client->authenticate($this->request->query['code']);
            $token = json_encode($client->getAccessToken());
            $credentialsPath =WWW_ROOT . 'files'. DS.'google.txt';
            if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
            }
            $file = new File($credentialsPath, true);
            $file->write($token);
            $client->setAccessToken($token);
            return $this->redirect(‘/add-event’);
        }
    }
```

**Add event functionality**

```
Public function add()
{
$client = $this->getClient();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $dateStart = new \DateTime($this->request->data['start_date_time'], new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
                $dateStart->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
                $startDate = $dateStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $dateEnd = new \DateTime($this->request->data['end_date_time'], new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
                $dateEnd->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
                $endDate = $dateEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $guests = $this->request->data['guests'];
                $eventGuest = [];
                $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
                foreach ($guests as $key => $value) {
                    $eventGuest[$key]['email'] = $value;
                }
                $eventData = [
                    'summary' => $this->request->data['name'],
                    'location' => $this->request->data['location'],
                    'description' => $this->request->data['description'],
                    'start' => [
                        'dateTime' => date("c", strtotime($startDate)),
                    ],
                    'end' => [
                        'dateTime' => date("c", strtotime($endDate)),
                    ],
                    'attendees' => $eventGuest,
                    'reminders' => [
                        'useDefault' => true,
                    ],
                    'visibility' => 'private',
                    'privateCopy' => true,
                ];
                $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event($eventData);
                $sendNotifications = ['sendNotifications' => true];
                $calendarId = 'primary';
                $eventDataResponse = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event, $sendNotifications);
          }

}
```

**Edit event**
//event id $id

```
Public function edit($id)
{
$client = $this->getClient();
 if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
                $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
                if (isset($eventID) && !empty($eventID)) {
                    $eventData = $service->events->get('primary', $eventID);
                }
                $guests = $this->request->data['guests'];
                $eventGuest = [];
                foreach ($guests as $key => $value) {
                    $eventGuest[$key]['email'] = $value;
                }
                $eventData->setSummary($this->request->data['name']);
                $eventData->setDescription($this->request->data['description']);
                $eventData->setLocation($this->request->data['location']);
                $eventData->setAttendees($eventGuest);
                $sendNotifications = ['sendNotifications' => true];
                $updatedEvent = $service->events->update('primary', $eventData->getId(), $eventData, $sendNotifications);
                                             $this->Flash->error(__('Event could not be update. Please, try again.'));
            }
}
Deleted event
//event id $id
// if google calendar in event is exist otherwise  not to dispaly
Public function delete($id)
{
 $client = $this->getClient();
            if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put', 'patch'])) {
 $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
                $sendNotifications = ['sendNotifications' => true];
                $service->events->delete('primary', $eventID, $sendNotifications);
    }
}
```